# Kibana 4 Color Scheme

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I tend towards darker color schemes when building GUIs, and some of the nicer screenshots that I've seen of Kibana support this. Now that we are kicking the tires on Kibana 4, the vizualizations and dashboards seem to be light background only. Is there a button staring me in the face that I'm missing, or is the color picking not (yet) available in version 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is an open issue in Kibana backlog regarding this:
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2906

**UPD:** 
Dark scheme was merged (https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/4702) and available in Kibana 4.2

See docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/dashboard.html